# Catch error when occures in OK method OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I have a use case: There will be an error on getting property in the model:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public Student ErrorProperty { get { throw new Exception(); } set { } }
}
```

I am trying to expand ErrorProperty:https://localhost:44383/odata/Student?$expand=ErrorProperty
In controller looks like everything is ok, it is not throwing any exception:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<TEntity> queryOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var list = new List<Student>
        {
            CreateNewStudent("Cody Allen", 130),
            CreateNewStudent("Todd Ostermeier", 160),
            CreateNewStudent("Viral Pandya", 140)
        };
        return Ok(list);
    }
```

After executing this method ('Get' method), the model throws an exception. In Postman I am  getting `Could not get response` error:
[image: Error]

Also, I created the error handler, but it is not catching this kind of exceptions:

```
 public class ODataExceptionHandler
{
    public static RequestDelegate HandleException()
    {
        return async context =>
        {
            await Handle(context);
        };
    }

    public static Task Handle(HttpContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(new Action(() =>
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/problem+json";
            var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exceptionHandlerPathFeature);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
            context.Response.Body.Write(byteArray);
        }));
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
  app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
        {
            errorApp.Run(ODataExceptionHandler.HandleException());
        });
```

How can I catch this kind of errors?

Comment: Your request didn't get to your controller from you post. Have u tried right url to access?

Comment: @Lightman, Controller is working. As you can see I put throw new Exception(); in getting ErrorProperty on the model. So I want to catch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Patient
{
    public ulong PatientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDateTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PatientForms> PatientForms { get; set; }


    public Patient ErrorProperty { get { throw new Exception(); } set { } }

}
```

**UPDATE 10/8/2020**

Adding `ExceptionHandler`

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //}
        //else
        //{
            //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(ODataExceptionHandler.HandleException());
            });

            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        //}
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "odata/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
            endpoints.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(10);

        });


    }
```

> Screenshot of test

[image]

> Steps of using OData

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddOData();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "odata/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
            endpoints.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(10);

        });
    }
```

Controller.cs

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Student")]
public class StudentsController : ODataController
{
    ...

    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var list = new List<Student>
        {
            CreateNewStudent("Cody Allen", 130),
            CreateNewStudent("Todd Ostermeier", 160),
            CreateNewStudent("Viral Pandya", 140)
        };
        return Ok(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this?  How can it fix my problem?

Comment: Did you understand the problem? My goal is to catch exception in this line: public Student ErrorProperty { get { throw new Exception(); } set { } }

Comment: I copied your exception to my project and it also works. Maybe you could check `Configure()` I updated above.

Comment: Ok. Just added the constructor to throw exception as you code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219544/discussion-between-dilshod-k-and-lightman).

Comment: something strange here. I got your project from GitHub. And it is working on that, but it is not working on my project. Maybe something wrong with my configuration. I will make this a correct answer.